# Use formula to get "B" Break Time for each agent in the first column

Tags: google-sheets, rtm, kronos-workforce-ready-suite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrSrq.png)

I want to know the correct function to use here to get the break for each agent

Answer (score 0):

**Paste** this formula in `A7`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$6:$Q$6,1,ArrayFormula(MATCH(1,SEARCH("B",E7:NQ7),0))),"No Break")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try in row 7:

```
 =INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(E7:R="B"; E6:P6; ));;9^9))))
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn79X.png